# Map not a function error when i'm trying to pass props to a child

Tags: reactjs

I'm stuck and out of ideas what's happening here:

This is the code for a child component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { ErrorBoundary } from "../../utils/ErrorBoundary";

class FrontCard extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {console.log(this.props)}{" "}
        {this.props.map((card, index) => (
          <Card key={index} style={{ width: "18rem" }}>
            <Card.Img variant="top" src="holder.js/100px180" />
            <Card.Body>
              <Card.Title>{card.title}</Card.Title>
              <Card.Text>{card.body} </Card.Text>
              <Button variant="primary">Go somewhere</Button>
            </Card.Body>
          </Card>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default FrontCard;
```

And this is how it's called:

```
        <FrontCard {...this.state.cards} />
```

As you can see I log the props just before mapping it, and the array is there in the console:

```
{0: {…}, 1: {…}, 2: {…}}
```

The question is, why it's saying that map is not a function?

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.props.map is not a function
    at FrontCard.render (FrontCard.jsx:44)
```

Comment: Your props is not an `Array`. It's an `object`. You can't `map` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `map` works on arrays and your `props` are an object. You need to convert that object to an array first before mapping it.

Change your map to the following:

```
{Object.keys(this.props).map((index) => (
  <Card key={index} style={{ width: "18rem" }}>
    <Card.Img variant="top" src="holder.js/100px180" />
    <Card.Body>
      <Card.Title>{this.props[index].title}</Card.Title>
      <Card.Text>{this.props[index].body} </Card.Text>
      <Button variant="primary">Go somewhere</Button>
    </Card.Body>
  </Card>
))}
```

---

But the better practice might be to do the following:

- Change the way you call the component to this:

```
<FrontCard cards={this.state.cards} />
```

- Then you can change the `map` to this:

```
{this.props.cards.map((card, index) => (
  <Card key={index} style={{ width: "18rem" }}>
    <Card.Img variant="top" src="holder.js/100px180" />
    <Card.Body>
      <Card.Title>{card.title}</Card.Title>
      <Card.Text>{card.body} </Card.Text>
      <Button variant="primary">Go somewhere</Button>
    </Card.Body>
  </Card>
))}
```

Answer (score 1):

- `this.props` is an `object` and not an `array`.
- `map` function is used to iterate over an `array`.
- Though if you want to go through it, try this:

```
var myObject = { 'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3 };

Object.keys(myObject).map(function(key, index) {
  myObject[key] += 1;
});

console.log(myObject);
// => { 'a': 2, 'b': 3, 'c': 4 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
{0: {…}, 1: {…}, 2: {…}}
```

This is not an array, it's an object. Component props are represented as an object. There's no map function on objects.

How to solve it is up to you, but I'd pass the cards as a prop to the FrontCard component.

```
 <FrontCard cards={this.state.cards} />
```

And then you can call map on the prop like this.

```
this.props.cards.map((card, index) => ..
```

Answer (score 1):

props is always an object in React components, what you're doing here is calling `map` which is a array method on an object. Try this:

```
<FrontCard card={this.state.cards} />
```

and then in component:

```
class FrontCard extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.cards.map((card, index) => (
          <Card key={index} style={{ width: "18rem" }}>
            <Card.Img variant="top" src="holder.js/100px180" />
            <Card.Body>
              <Card.Title>{card.title}</Card.Title>
              <Card.Text>{card.body} </Card.Text>
              <Button variant="primary">Go somewhere</Button>
            </Card.Body>
          </Card>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```