# TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined / TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have a component which seeks to render data available to it in `props` as react bootstrap cards by `map`ing over the data and calling a function to render the necessary components.

In Chrome dev tools for React this data (`props.data`) looked like an array, but I now realise that being in props it is actually an object.  To handle this I use
`const values = Object.values(this.props.data);` and then later `<CardDeck>{values.map(renderCard)}</CardDeck>`.  I have put the full component code at the bottom of this question.

The array (`const values`) has this structure:

```
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "5f78532c82c81067eafdb896"
    },
    "card_id": "Was-Tre-2140",
    "brand": "National Treasures",
    "card_number": {
      "$numberDouble": "100"
    },
    "career_stage": "Veteran",
    "forTrade": "Yes",
    "image_path": "https://res.cloudinary.com/dkwmxhsem/image/upload/t_Card Resize/v1599758190/",
    "manufacturer": "Panini",
    "number": {
      "$numberDouble": "16"
    },
    "player": "Trent Williams",
    "print_run": {
      "$numberDouble": "25"
    },
    "purchase_date": "Thu Aug 20 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2020",
    "series": "Century Materials",
    "status": "Own",
    "team": "Washington Football Team",
    "type": "Auto",
    "user": "jinky32@gmail.com",
    "variation": "Holo Silver",
    "year": "2010"
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "5f78533d82c81067eafdc06d"
    },
    "card_id": "Was-Ter-4383",
    "brand": "National Treasures",
    "card_number": {
      "$numberDouble": "187"
    },
    "career_stage": "Rookie Card",
    "forTrade": "",
    "image_path": "https://res.cloudinary.com/dkwmxhsem/image/upload/t_Card Resize/v1599758190/",
    "manufacturer": "Panini",
    "number": {
      "$numberDouble": "1"
    },
    "player": "Terry McLaurin",
    "print_run": {
      "$numberDouble": "10"
    },
    "purchase_date": "Sat Oct 03 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2020",
    "series": "Rookie Autograph Patch",
    "status": "Own",
    "team": "Washington Football Team",
    "type": "RPA",
    "user": "jinky32@gmail.com",
    "variation": "Holo Gold",
    "year": "2019"
  }
]
```

Everything renders to the screen correctly until I try to access the data in objects such as

```
"card_number": {
      "$numberDouble": "229"
    },
```

this is done in the render function, section:

```
<Card.Title>
  {card.player}(#
  {card.card_number.$numberDouble}) <---It blows up here!
</Card.Title>
```

This throws an error `TypeError: Cannot read property '$numberDouble' of undefined`

If I use

```
<Card.Title>
  {card.player}(#
  {card.card_number}) 
</Card.Title>
```

I get the error `Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {$numberDouble}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`

So I've tried converting to an array and this seems to work in javascript

```js
let values = [
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "5f78532c82c81067eafdb896"
    },
    "card_id": "Was-Tre-2140",
    "brand": "National Treasures",
    "card_number": {
      "$numberDouble": "100"
    },
    "career_stage": "Veteran",
    "forTrade": "Yes",
    "image_path": "https://res.cloudinary.com/dkwmxhsem/image/upload/t_Card Resize/v1599758190/",
    "manufacturer": "Panini",
    "number": {
      "$numberDouble": "16"
    },
    "player": "Trent Williams",
    "print_run": {
      "$numberDouble": "25"
    },
    "purchase_date": "Thu Aug 20 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2020",
    "series": "Century Materials",
    "status": "Own",
    "team": "Washington Football Team",
    "type": "Auto",
    "user": "jinky32@gmail.com",
    "variation": "Holo Silver",
    "year": "2010"
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "5f78533d82c81067eafdc06d"
    },
    "card_id": "Was-Ter-4383",
    "brand": "National Treasures",
    "card_number": {
      "$numberDouble": "187"
    },
    "career_stage": "Rookie Card",
    "forTrade": "",
    "image_path": "https://res.cloudinary.com/dkwmxhsem/image/upload/t_Card Resize/v1599758190/",
    "manufacturer": "Panini",
    "number": {
      "$numberDouble": "1"
    },
    "player": "Terry McLaurin",
    "print_run": {
      "$numberDouble": "10"
    },
    "purchase_date": "Sat Oct 03 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2020",
    "series": "Rookie Autograph Patch",
    "status": "Own",
    "team": "Washington Football Team",
    "type": "RPA",
    "user": "jinky32@gmail.com",
    "variation": "Holo Gold",
    "year": "2019"
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "5f78533f82c81067eafdc14a"
    },
    "card_id": "Was-Ant-9898",
    "brand": "Black",
    "card_number": {
      "$numberDouble": "229"
    },
    "career_stage": "Rookie Card",
    "forTrade": "",
    "image_path": "https://res.cloudinary.com/dkwmxhsem/image/upload/t_Card Resize/v1599758190/",
    "manufacturer": "Panini",
    "number": {
      "$numberDouble": "114"
    },
    "player": "Antonio Gibson",
    "print_run": {
      "$numberDouble": "199"
    },
    "purchase_date": "Thu Sep 10 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2020",
    "series": "Rookie Patch Autographs",
    "status": "Own",
    "team": "Washington Football Team",
    "type": "RPA",
    "user": "jinky32@gmail.com",
    "variation": "Base",
    "year": "2020"
  }
]
const renderCard = (card, index) => {

console.log(Object.values(card.card_number)[0])

      }

values.map(renderCard)
```

but if I use it in my component

```
<Card.Title>
  {card.player}(#
  {Object.values(card.card_number)[0]}) {card.variation}
</Card.Title>
```

it gives an error `TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object`.

I'm starting to go slightly crazy - can anyone advise on the best way to access these values?

**Full Code**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import CardDeck from "react-bootstrap/CardDeck";
import Card from "react-bootstrap/Card";
import Col from "react-bootstrap/Col";
import Container from "react-bootstrap/Container";
import ListGroup from "react-bootstrap/ListGroup";
import ListGroupItem from "react-bootstrap/ListGroupItem";
import { Image, CloudinaryContext, Transformation } from "cloudinary-react";

class CardColumns extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.loadCardData(this.props.path);
  }

  render() {
    // const data = Array.from(this.props.data);
    const values = Object.values(this.props.data);
    // const data = JSON.stringify(this.props.data);
    // const data = this.props.data;
    console.log("HERE IS DATA " + JSON.stringify(values));
    const renderCard = (card, index) => {
      return (
        // TODO: Looks at setting default heght (white space? on images so the last two classes below can be removed)
        <Col className="container-fluid mt-4 d-flex align-items-stretch">
          {/* <Card key={index} className="box"> */}
          <CloudinaryContext cloudName="dkwmxhsem">
            <Card
              style={{ width: "18rem" }}
              key={index}
              className="box h-100"
              border="danger"
            >
              <Card.Header>
                {card.brand} - {card.series}
              </Card.Header>
              <Card.Img
                variant="top"
                src={`${card.image_path}${card.card_id}.jpg`}
                fluid
              />

              <Card.Body>
                <Card.Title>
                  {card.player}(#
                  {/* {card.card_number}) {card.variation} */}
                  {Object.values(card.card_number)}) {card.variation}
                  {/* {card.card_number.$numberDouble}) {card.variation} */}
                  {/* {card.card_number}) {card.variation} */}
                </Card.Title>
              </Card.Body>
              <ListGroup className="list-group-flush">
                <ListGroupItem>
                  <b>Print Run - </b>
                  {/* {card.print_run.$numberDouble} */}
                </ListGroupItem>
                <ListGroupItem>
                  <b>Career Stage -</b> {card.career_stage}{" "}
                </ListGroupItem>
                <ListGroupItem>
                  <b>For Trade -</b> {card.forTrade}
                </ListGroupItem>
              </ListGroup>
              <Card.Footer className="text-muted ">{card.team}</Card.Footer>
            </Card>
          </CloudinaryContext>
        </Col>
      );
    };

    return (
      // look at answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61149898/map-not-a-function-error-when-im-trying-to-pass-props-to-a-child
      <Container>
        <h1>Hello {this.props.num}</h1>

        <CardDeck>{values.map(renderCard)}</CardDeck>
        {/* <CardDeck>{data.map(renderCard)}</CardDeck> */}
        {/* <CardDeck>{Object.keys(this.props.data).map(renderCard)}</CardDeck> */}

        {/* <CardDeck>{this.props.data.map(renderCard)}</CardDeck> */}
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
export default CardColumns;
```

Below is the output of `console.log("HERE IS DATA " + JSON.stringify(values));`

```
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "5f78532c82c81067eafdb896"
    },
    "card_id": "Was-Tre-2140",
    "brand": "National Treasures",
    "card_number": {
      "$numberDouble": "100"
    },
    "career_stage": "Veteran",
    "forTrade": "Yes",
    "image_path": "https://res.cloudinary.com/dkwmxhsem/image/upload/t_Card Resize/v1599758190/",
    "manufacturer": "Panini",
    "number": {
      "$numberDouble": "16"
    },
    "player": "Trent Williams",
    "print_run": {
      "$numberDouble": "25"
    },
    "purchase_date": "Thu Aug 20 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2020",
    "series": "Century Materials",
    "status": "Own",
    "team": "Washington Football Team",
    "type": "Auto",
    "user": "jinky32@gmail.com",
    "variation": "Holo Silver",
    "year": "2010"
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "5f78532d82c81067eafdb906"
    },
    "card_id": "Was-Rya-6543",
    "brand": "Playbook",
    "card_number": {
      "$numberDouble": "85"
    },
    "career_stage": "Rookie Card",
    "forTrade": "",
    "image_path": "https://res.cloudinary.com/dkwmxhsem/image/upload/t_Card Resize/v1599758190/",
    "manufacturer": "Panini",
    "number": {
      "$numberDouble": "80"
    },
    "player": "Ryan Kerrigan",
    "print_run": {
      "$numberDouble": "299"
    },
    "purchase_date": "Tue Sep 01 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2020",
    "series": "Rookie Signatures",
    "status": "Own",
    "team": "Washington Football Team",
    "type": "Auto",
    "user": "jinky32@gmail.com",
    "variation": "Base",
    "year": "2011"
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "5f78532f82c81067eafdba3f"
    },
    "card_id": "Was-Jaw-3977",
    "brand": "Contenders ",
    "card_number": {
      "$numberDouble": "144"
    },
    "career_stage": "Rookie Card",
    "forTrade": "Yes",
    "image_path": "https://res.cloudinary.com/dkwmxhsem/image/upload/t_Card Resize/v1599758190/",
    "manufacturer": "Panini",
    "number": {
      "$numberDouble": "0"
    },
    "player": "Jawan Jamison",
    "print_run": {
      "$numberDouble": "21"
    },
    "purchase_date": "Mon Sep 14 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2020",
    "series": "Rookie Ticket Autographs",
    "status": "Own",
    "team": "Washington Football Team",
    "type": "Auto",
    "user": "jinky32@gmail.com",
    "variation": "Cracked Ice",
    "year": "2013"
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "5f78533082c81067eafdbaaf"
    },
    "card_id": "Was-Jor-5709",
    "brand": "National Treasures",
    "card_number": {
      "$numberDouble": "214"
    },
    "career_stage": "Rookie Card",
    "forTrade": "",
    "image_path": "https://res.cloudinary.com/dkwmxhsem/image/upload/t_Card Resize/v1599758190/",
    "manufacturer": "Panini",
    "number": {
      "$numberDouble": "0"
    },
    "player": "Jordan Reed",
    "print_run": {
      "$numberDouble": "5"
    },
    "purchase_date": "Tue Sep 15 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2020",
    "series": "Rookie Material Signatures",
    "status": "Own",
    "team": "Washington Football Team",
    "type": "RPA",
    "user": "jinky32@gmail.com",
    "variation": "Platinum",
    "year": "2013"
  },

  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "5f78533e82c81067eafdc104"
    },
    "card_id": "Was-Ant-5549",
    "brand": "Black",
    "card_number": {
      "$numberDouble": "229"
    },
    "career_stage": "Rookie Card",
    "forTrade": "",
    "image_path": "https://res.cloudinary.com/dkwmxhsem/image/upload/t_Card Resize/v1599758190/",
    "manufacturer": "Panini",
    "number": {
      "$numberDouble": "3"
    },
    "player": "Antonio Gibson",
    "print_run": {
      "$numberDouble": "10"
    },
    "purchase_date": "Fri Sep 11 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2020",
    "series": "Rookie Patch Autographs",
    "status": "Own",
    "team": "Washington Football Team",
    "type": "RPA",
    "user": "jinky32@gmail.com",
    "variation": "Emerald",
    "year": "2020"
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "5f78533e82c81067eafdc12f"
    },
    "card_id": "Was-Ant-7597",
    "brand": "Black",
    "card_number": {
      "$numberDouble": "229"
    },
    "career_stage": "Rookie Card",
    "forTrade": "",
    "image_path": "https://res.cloudinary.com/dkwmxhsem/image/upload/t_Card Resize/v1599758190/",
    "manufacturer": "Panini",
    "number": {
      "$numberDouble": "76"
    },
    "player": "Antonio Gibson",
    "print_run": {
      "$numberDouble": "99"
    },
    "purchase_date": "Thu Sep 10 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2020",
    "series": "Rookie Patch Autographs",
    "status": "Own",
    "team": "Washington Football Team",
    "type": "RPA",
    "user": "jinky32@gmail.com",
    "variation": "Base",
    "year": "2020"
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "5f78533f82c81067eafdc14a"
    },
    "card_id": "Was-Ant-9898",
    "brand": "Black",
    "card_number": {
      "$numberDouble": "229"
    },
    "career_stage": "Rookie Card",
    "forTrade": "",
    "image_path": "https://res.cloudinary.com/dkwmxhsem/image/upload/t_Card Resize/v1599758190/",
    "manufacturer": "Panini",
    "number": {
      "$numberDouble": "114"
    },
    "player": "Antonio Gibson",
    "print_run": {
      "$numberDouble": "199"
    },
    "purchase_date": "Thu Sep 10 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2020",
    "series": "Rookie Patch Autographs",
    "status": "Own",
    "team": "Washington Football Team",
    "type": "RPA",
    "user": "jinky32@gmail.com",
    "variation": "Base",
    "year": "2020"
  }
]
```

The (truncated) output of `console.log("HERE IS DATA " + JSON.stringify(this.props.data)` is

```
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "5f78532c82c81067eafdb896"
    },
    "card_id": "Was-Tre-2140",
    "brand": "National Treasures",
    "card_number": {
      "$numberDouble": "100"
    },
    "career_stage": "Veteran",
    "forTrade": "Yes",
    "image_path": "https://res.cloudinary.com/dkwmxhsem/image/upload/t_Card Resize/v1599758190/",
    "manufacturer": "Panini",
    "number": {
      "$numberDouble": "16"
    },
    "player": "Trent Williams",
    "print_run": {
      "$numberDouble": "25"
    },
    "purchase_date": "Thu Aug 20 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2020",
    "series": "Century Materials",
    "status": "Own",
    "team": "Washington Football Team",
    "type": "Auto",
    "user": "jinky32@gmail.com",
    "variation": "Holo Silver",
    "year": "2010"
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "5f78533c82c81067eafdc048"
    },
    "card_id": "Was-Mon-3547",
    "brand": "National Treasures",
    "card_number": {
      "$numberDouble": "107"
    },
    "career_stage": "Rookie Card",
    "forTrade": "No",
    "image_path": "https://res.cloudinary.com/dkwmxhsem/image/upload/t_Card Resize/v1599758190/",
    "manufacturer": "Panini",
    "number": {
      "$numberDouble": "60"
    },
    "player": "Montez Sweat",
    "print_run": {
      "$numberDouble": "99"
    },
    "purchase_date": "Thu Aug 20 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2020",
    "series": "Rookie Signatures",
    "status": "Own",
    "team": "Washington Football Team",
    "type": "Auto",
    "user": "jinky32@gmail.com",
    "variation": "Base",
    "year": "2019"
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "5f78533d82c81067eafdc05c"
    },
    "card_id": "Was-Ter-2762",
    "brand": "Immaculate",
    "card_number": {
      "$numberDouble": "19"
    },
    "career_stage": "Rookie Card",
    "forTrade": "No",
    "image_path": "https://res.cloudinary.com/dkwmxhsem/image/upload/t_Card Resize/v1599758190/",
    "manufacturer": "Panini",
    "number": {
      "$numberDouble": "19"
    },
    "player": "Terry McLaurin",
    "print_run": {
      "$numberDouble": "99"
    },
    "purchase_date": "Tue Aug 18 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2020",
    "series": "Rookie Patch Autographs",
    "status": "Own",
    "team": "Washington Football Team",
    "type": "RPA",
    "user": "jinky32@gmail.com",
    "variation": "Base",
    "year": "2019"
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "5f78533d82c81067eafdc06d"
    },
    "card_id": "Was-Ter-4383",
    "brand": "National Treasures",
    "card_number": {
      "$numberDouble": "187"
    },
    "career_stage": "Rookie Card",
    "forTrade": "",
    "image_path": "https://res.cloudinary.com/dkwmxhsem/image/upload/t_Card Resize/v1599758190/",
    "manufacturer": "Panini",
    "number": {
      "$numberDouble": "1"
    },
    "player": "Terry McLaurin",
    "print_run": {
      "$numberDouble": "10"
    },
    "purchase_date": "Sat Oct 03 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2020",
    "series": "Rookie Autograph Patch",
    "status": "Own",
    "team": "Washington Football Team",
    "type": "RPA",
    "user": "jinky32@gmail.com",
    "variation": "Holo Gold",
    "year": "2019"
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "5f78533d82c81067eafdc0a8"
    },
    "card_id": "Was-Ter-4384",
    "brand": "National Treasures",
    "card_number": {
      "$numberDouble": "187"
    },
    "career_stage": "Rookie Card",
    "forTrade": "No",
    "image_path": "https://res.cloudinary.com/dkwmxhsem/image/upload/t_Card Resize/v1599758190/",
    "manufacturer": "Panini",
    "number": {
      "$numberDouble": "8"
    },
    "player": "Terry McLaurin",
    "print_run": {
      "$numberDouble": "10"
    },
    "purchase_date": "Sun Sep 06 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2020",
    "series": "Rookie Autograph Patch",
    "status": "Own",
    "team": "Washington Football Team",
    "type": "RPA",
    "user": "jinky32@gmail.com",
    "variation": "Holo Gold",
    "year": "2019"
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "5f78533e82c81067eafdc0f1"
    },
    "card_id": "Was-Ter-4359",
    "brand": "National Treasures",
    "card_number": {
      "$numberDouble": "187"
    },
    "career_stage": "Rookie Card",
    "forTrade": "",
    "image_path": "https://res.cloudinary.com/dkwmxhsem/image/upload/t_Card Resize/v1599758190/",
    "manufacturer": "Panini",
    "number": {
      "$numberDouble": "5"
    },
    "player": "Terry McLaurin",
    "print_run": {
      "$numberDouble": "10"
    },
    "purchase_date": "Thu Sep 24 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2020",
    "series": "Rookie Autograph Patch",
    "status": "Own",
    "team": "Washington Football Team",
    "type": "RPA",
    "user": "jinky32@gmail.com",
    "variation": "Holo Gold",
    "year": "2019"
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "5f78533e82c81067eafdc104"
    },
    "card_id": "Was-Ant-5549",
    "brand": "Black",
    "card_number": {
      "$numberDouble": "229"
    },
    "career_stage": "Rookie Card",
    "forTrade": "",
    "image_path": "https://res.cloudinary.com/dkwmxhsem/image/upload/t_Card Resize/v1599758190/",
    "manufacturer": "Panini",
    "number": {
      "$numberDouble": "3"
    },
    "player": "Antonio Gibson",
    "print_run": {
      "$numberDouble": "10"
    },
    "purchase_date": "Fri Sep 11 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2020",
    "series": "Rookie Patch Autographs",
    "status": "Own",
    "team": "Washington Football Team",
    "type": "RPA",
    "user": "jinky32@gmail.com",
    "variation": "Emerald",
    "year": "2020"
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "5f78533e82c81067eafdc12f"
    },
    "card_id": "Was-Ant-7597",
    "brand": "Black",
    "card_number": {
      "$numberDouble": "229"
    },
    "career_stage": "Rookie Card",
    "forTrade": "",
    "image_path": "https://res.cloudinary.com/dkwmxhsem/image/upload/t_Card Resize/v1599758190/",
    "manufacturer": "Panini",
    "number": {
      "$numberDouble": "76"
    },
    "player": "Antonio Gibson",
    "print_run": {
      "$numberDouble": "99"
    },
    "purchase_date": "Thu Sep 10 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2020",
    "series": "Rookie Patch Autographs",
    "status": "Own",
    "team": "Washington Football Team",
    "type": "RPA",
    "user": "jinky32@gmail.com",
    "variation": "Base",
    "year": "2020"
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "5f78533f82c81067eafdc14a"
    },
    "card_id": "Was-Ant-9898",
    "brand": "Black",
    "card_number": {
      "$numberDouble": "229"
    },
    "career_stage": "Rookie Card",
    "forTrade": "",
    "image_path": "https://res.cloudinary.com/dkwmxhsem/image/upload/t_Card Resize/v1599758190/",
    "manufacturer": "Panini",
    "number": {
      "$numberDouble": "114"
    },
    "player": "Antonio Gibson",
    "print_run": {
      "$numberDouble": "199"
    },
    "purchase_date": "Thu Sep 10 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2020",
    "series": "Rookie Patch Autographs",
    "status": "Own",
    "team": "Washington Football Team",
    "type": "RPA",
    "user": "jinky32@gmail.com",
    "variation": "Base",
    "year": "2020"
  }
]
```

Here is looks like an object.  However if I select the component in Chrome dev tools and `$r` in console I get the below
[image]

If I run `$r.props` I see the images below (second showing the data object expanded)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply - I have added it at the bottom of the question

Comment: why are you doing this - `Object.values(this.props.data);` and not just accessing `this.props.data`? Props might be an object but that doesnt mean the data is. It sounds like you are complicating things for yourself. What is output of `console.log(this.props.data)`

Comment: Thanks for your help @Craicerjack.  I've added what you requested to the bottom of the original question and also shown the output of `$r` when the react component is selected.

Comment: Yeah so `this.props.data` is an array.

Comment: @Craicerjack that's where I started on this crazy journey :).  But if i use `<CardDeck>{this.props.data.map(renderCard)}</CardDeck>` I get `TypeError: this.props.data.map is not a function` which I thought was telling me that `this.props.data` is not an array

Comment: Is the data coming from an asynchronous call? it might not yet be loaded

Comment: @craicerjack it is, but it's called in app.js and stored in state. It's passed down to this component in a prop and I can see it in props.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the sample data which you have provided, I see the data. Probably some of your data might not be having card_number.

You may try like this

```
{card?.card_number && `(#${Object.values(card.card_number)})`} 
{card?.card_number?.$numberDouble && `(#${card.card_number.$numberDouble})` }
```

Check the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-haibt-cdlkr?file=/src/data.json)